# Piping output of serial port to curl with for loop in cmd

Tags: batch-file, cmd, serial-port

I would like to grab the output of a serial port. There is a message sent in UTF-8 over it.

Now i need to send this message i received via serial port to a HTTP-API with CURL.exe

What i first tried was to open the port in the cmd with "type com5:". That worked fine and the port was opened and monitored. I saw the message in the cmd and when i used "type com5: >> output.txt" the message was written in the file.

After that i tried to put the "type com5:"-Command inside a for loop in cmd to send the message whenever one is received with CURL to an API.

The code i used:

```
cd C:\comcon\
for /F %%i in ('type com5:') do set message=%%i & curl.exe http://sample.com/api.php?message=%message%
```

With this code it doesn't work. Messages received over the serial port aren't processed inside the for loop and it seems the loop isn't even triggered.

Anyone has an idea or another solution to monitor the serial port for new messages and send these messages to an API via calling an url with parameters.

Thank you so much in advance!

Comment: Change `set message=%%i & curl.exe http://sample.com/api.php?message=%message%` to `set "message=%%i"` then on the next line use `curl.exe http://sample.com/api.php?message=%message%`. Alternatively you can deal with the delayed expansion issue instead. Another method would be to not set anything to a variable, by changing `set message=%%i & curl.exe http://sample.com/api.php?message=%message%` to `curl.exe http://sample.com/api.php?message=%%i`. You may wish to consider using tokens, delimiters and end of line options. Unicode or character set issues are outside of the scope of this comment.

Comment: Thank you for the help. I tried that but the problem is still there. It seems that the messages aren't even processed inside the for loop. If I use type com5: in the cmd the messages are shown but now i tested with 
for /F %%i in ('type com5:') do (
set message=%%i
echo %message% >> outtest.txt
) 
to test if maybe curl or the api is the problem, but even with echo theres no output.

Comment: Don't assign variable `message`, use `%%i` directly...

Comment: Thank you both for responding. I tried now to set the delims, but i am stucked at that point. This is my code now: cd C:\comcon\

setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

for /F "delims= " %%i in ('cmd /k type com5:') do (
echo %%i >> outtest.txt) Doesn't work.

Comment: Maybe the continuously monitoring of the comport trough "type com5:" prevents the loop from stepping forward and processing the received message? Maybe thats the problem, because if i use type com5: in the cmd the command runs until its manually cancelled.

Comment: That makes sense, _which is more than I can say for your decision to enable delayed expansion_, but surely you realise that `Cmd /K` opens a `cmd.exe` and `K`eeps it open until you close it? Where in the advice did anyone tell you to use `cmd /k`? so why have you added it?

Comment: I'm guessing: When you use `type com5:` on the command line, do have to use CTRL-C to stop the command after you receive the message?

Answer (score 0):

I would use two threads.
One for receiving the message from the com-port and one to process it.
This avoids the blocking `FOR /F`.
But you will have to kill the first thread, because it can't be stopped automatically.

```
@echo off
REM *** Trampoline jump for function calls of the form ex. "C:\:function:\..\<batch>.bat"
FOR /F "tokens=3 delims=:" %%L in ("%~0") DO goto :%%L

break > async.tmp

start "" /b %~d0/:thread_read:/../%~pnx0

goto :process
exit /b

:thread_read
echo STARTING
type com5_ > async.tmp
echo END THREAD
exit

:process
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
call :_process  < async.tmp
exit /b

:_process
set "line="
set /p line=
if not defined line (
    goto :_process
)

echo ## !line!
```